# Wordpress - Change Last Item in Post Type Query

Tags: wordpress

I have setup a custom Post Type in WordPress and have a question.  How can I have WordPress assign the last item in my query a different class?

Here is my code: (This works perfect...)

```
    <?php       
    $args = array('post_type' => 'testimonial_quote', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // The Loop
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="quote-main">
            <p class="quote"><?php echo get_field('testimonial_item'); ?></p>
            <p class="name"><?php echo get_field('testimonial_name_item'); ?></p>
            <p class="company"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php   
    $i++;
    endwhile;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

For the last item in my list -- I need it to be:

```
    <div class="quote-main-final">
        <p class="quote"><?php echo get_field('testimonial_item'); ?></p>
        <p class="name"><?php echo get_field('testimonial_name_item'); ?></p>
        <p class="company"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    </div>
```

(Basically changing the class name of "quote-main" to "quote-main-final" for the final item that it pulls)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count your results

```
<?php      
$args = array('post_type' => 'testimonial_quote', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// Count your recordset
$counter = $the_query->post_count;
// The Loop
$i = 0;
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="quote-main<?php echo(($i == $counter - 1)?'-final':'');?>">
<p class="quote"><?php echo get_field('testimonial_item'); ?></p>
<p class="name"><?php echo get_field('testimonial_name_item'); ?></p>
<p class="company"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
</div>
<?php   
$i++;
endwhile;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This half worked.  It put the -final class on the first item in the list instead of the last item. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh my, you're absolutely right, my bad. Instead of sizeof() use $counter = $the_query->post_count;

Comment: Kostis, would you mind looking at another issue that I am having? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998705/wordpress-grab-item-by-category-in-post-type-query